# How can I invoke a method on an object using the Reflection API?

Tags: java, reflection

How do I invoke a method (e.g. setter inside object class) on an already existing object using Java reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
Object yourObject = ...;
Class clazz = yourObject.getClass();
Method setter = clazz.getMethod("setString", String.class); // You need to specify the parameter types
Object[] params = new Object[]{"New String"};
setter.invoke(this, params); // 'this' represents the class from were you calling that method.
// If you have a static method you can pass 'null' instead.
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a great tutorial [HERE](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html).

Answer (score 1):

See the [Reflection Trail](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
Class cls = obj.getClass();
Method m = cls.getMethod("yourMethod", String.class); // assuming there is a method of signature yourMethod(String x);
m.invoke(obj, "strValue");
```